# Combining multiple Routing tasks of Google OR-Tools

Tags: constraints, or-tools, capacity

I want to solve a VRP with some constraints. Let's say I got a network of nodes (= electric omnibus network) and each node represents a busline. Each node has attributes like starting and end time and energy consumption. 
My idea is to use the code for a [VRPTW](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/vrptw) and add the constraint of the energy consumption as [capacity of a node](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/cvrp) . 
This way I could manage that after a bus does a specific line, it only drives to the lines that are possible to fulfill concerning the time window (means: if he can or can not reach f.ex. line 30 before its starting time) and concerning the enery capacity (every bus has a battery and the energy consumption must not bring it below a certain point x. Point x means the bus can drive the line and still have enough energy left to reach the closest loading facility). 
I tried to add the capacity constraint with the [`AddDimension()`](https://developers.google.com/optimization/routing/dimensions) functionality, but it doesn't work out the way I want it to. 
My question is: is it even possible to realize my idea with the current state of OR-Tools and if yes, how is it done best?
I do it with Python.

Comment: It is very much possible to implement it the way the described. There's probably something wrong with the code. If you provide the relevant code I can try and help figure out what is wrong.

Comment: @Fuseques I found a nice example that covers my problem. I might take you up to your offer, if I might face a problem with it. Are you fine with that? :)